# Deploy CLI tool as package

Tags: python, pipenv

I develop a cli tool with Python for in-house use.

I would like to introduce pipenv to my project to manage "dependencies of dependencies". It is because I encountered a bug due to a difference between production environment and development environment.

However, MY cli tool is installed as a package.([httpie](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie) and [ansible](https://github.com/ansible/ansible) takes this strategy).
So, I have to specify all dependencies in setup.py.

How should I import "dependencies of dependencies" in Pipfile.lock to setup.py?
(or should take other method?)

Comment: As an alternative, consider deploying a conda package.

Answer (score 0):

It is suggested that you to do this the other way around. Instead of referencing dependencies in Pipfile, you should list them in setup.py instead, and reference them in Pipfile with

```
pipenv install -e .
```